# Wix Causing Redirect Issues for WP-Admin

Tags: web-hosting, wordpress

My company's first site was on wix.com.  We're now switching to WordPress, and it's caused issues.

So basically how we have it, is we bought our domain, and we were redirecting it to our wix site.  But now when I go to the wp-admin URL it tries to redirect it to wix.

So `example.com/wp-admin` redirects to a 404 on Wix.

Is there anyway to have it still redirect to Wix but to be able to use that URL to do some work on our new site?

Comment: How did you set up the redirect?

Comment: "Is there anyway to have it still redirect to Wix but..." - so you are still redirecting to Wix? Also, bear in mind that any previous 301 redirects will have been cached by your (and everyone else's) browser.

Comment: I am not sure why the down vote, but I did what I could. I wish I had an answer for you. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

To clarify, you want to be able to develop the wordpress site while the site continues to work at Wix, right?

You need to make sure your hosting service supports temporary URLs like `http://123.456.789.000/~user` then change the 2 URLS in your wordpress dashboard settings to that.

Then you will be able to access the dashboard via `http://123.456.789.000/~user/wp-admin`

When you are ready to go live, you change the settings to the proper URL, change the nameservers or DNS so your site points to your wordpress install and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a screenshot of the root directory of a WordPress install.  When you type www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin you are really loading www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/index.php which in turn loads /wp-login.php in the root folder along with a number of files in all of these folders. Some are checked, some are loaded, some are referenced when WordPress initializes.

My recommendation is to keep WordPress and Wix totally separate from each other. When you are ready to launch your WP site, let everyone know the day has come and do the unveiling. Until then, keep them separate...

Another choice would be to install WordPress in a separate folder such as in www.yourdomain.com/wp In that case you may have better luck with redirecting from your root folder. I still do not recommend it.

I am not an expert on .htaccess nor on WordPress. My recommendation is based on my personal experiences.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect with mod_rewrite, you can set up a rewrite condition such that it will redirect everything *except* `wp-admin`:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-
RewriteRule    (.*)  http://mywixsite.example.com/$1  [R]
```

Comment: Do not forget that WordPress wp-admin loads wp-login and several other php files during login and initialization.

Comment: In that case the rule needs to be `!^/wp-` instead of `!^/wp-admin` to handle wp-login.    Do the other files also fallow the `wp-` pattern?

Comment: Not necessarily. See my answer above with some of the files and folders listed.